# Chart.js 3 - How to count MySQL entries by month and display them in a bar chart

Tags: php, mysql, chart.js

I have a database with entries I'd like to count per month and display them in a yearly bar chart from Jan to Dec.
I must admit I'm fairly new to MySQL and PHP so please bear with me.
I can see the chart canvas but there is no data shown.
I just can't figure out how to get the data to show in the chart.

**DB Query**

```
//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT aangemaakt FROM afwijkings_rapporten ORDER BY aangemaakt");

//execute query
$result = $pdo->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

**CREATE**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `afwijkings_rapporten` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `naam` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `afdeling` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `aangemaakt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `pdnummer` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**INSERT**

Inserted data is: id, naam, afdeling, aangemaakt, pdnummer

```
INSERT INTO afwijkings_rapporten VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

**$data**

```
[
  {"aangemaakt":"2023-02-25 11:08:00","0":"2023-02-25 11:08:00"},
  {"aangemaakt":"2023-02-25 11:14:00","0":"2023-02-25 11:14:00"},
  {"aangemaakt":"2023-03-25 13:07:00","0":"2023-03-25 13:07:00"},
  {"aangemaakt":"2023-04-06 16:28:00","0":"2023-04-06 16:28:00"},
  {"aangemaakt":"2023-05-09 09:12:00","0":"2023-05-09 09:12:00"},
  {"aangemaakt":"2023-06-09 09:12:00","0":"2023-06-09 09:12:00"},
  {"aangemaakt":"2023-07-09 09:12:00","0":"2023-07-09 09:12:00"},
  {"aangemaakt":"2023-08-09 09:12:00","0":"2023-08-09 09:12:00"},
  {"aangemaakt":"2023-09-09 09:12:00","0":"2023-09-09 09:12:00"},
  {"aangemaakt":"2023-10-09 09:12:00","0":"2023-10-09 09:12:00"},
  {"aangemaakt":"2023-10-09 09:12:05","0":"2023-10-09 09:12:05"},
  {"aangemaakt":"2023-10-09 09:12:20","0":"2023-10-09 09:12:20"}
]
```

**Chart.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "chartdata.php",
    method: "GET",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var aangemaakt = [];

      for(var i in data) {
        aangemaakt.push(data[i].aangemaakt);
      }

      var data = {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mrt', 'Apr', 'Mei', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        datasets: [{
          label: 'Aantal rapporten per maand',
          data: aangemaakt,
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(229,31,47,1)',
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      };

      const config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: data,
        options: {
          responsive: true,
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          scales: {
            y: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }
        },
        // plugins: [ChartDataLabels]
      };

      const aantalPerMaand = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('aantalPerMaand'),
        config
      );

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please update your question with the structure of your table and some sample data (INSERTs or markdown table). At the moment your data passed to the chart config is an array of dates but with the axis configured to start at zero. I am not sure what you are expecting it to produce.

Comment: @nnichols updated my question with INSERT

Comment: If you need something other than the counts by month, you will need to update your question with the DDL (`CREATE TABLE ...`), sample data and an explanation of the desired output. My answer still stands.

Comment: No I only need counts per month. I tried your answer but after the db query, $data is empty.

Comment: @nnichols Added CREATE query

Comment: Is this a MySQL problem, a PHP problem, or a chart.js problem? You should check whether the markup is generated as expected to rule that out

Comment: Have you tried running the query in your db tool of choice? Do you get an error or just empty result set?

Comment: When I run the query in phpMyAdmin it returns an empty result set

Comment: Then it would appear you have no data between `2022-03-01` and current datetime. You might need to change the where clause to suit your needs.

Comment: That is true. I only have data for 2023.  I only need the monthly count for the current year. Can the query be edited to also count 0 (zero) for that month if no data is available?

Comment: Yes, but you can ask that as a separate question when this question has been answered. This question is already far broader than should normally be answered on SO. For the sake of getting your page showing a chart, just remove the WHERE clause from the query so it returns grouped data for all months in your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we don't know what your `afwijkings_rapporten` table contains, other than a datetime in `aangemaakt`, here is a simple suggestion to get you started.

This query will get you 12 months of data (including current month):

```php
// query to get data from the table
$query = <<<'SQL'
        SELECT
            DATE_FORMAT(`aangemaakt`, '%Y%m') AS `grp`,
            DATE_FORMAT(`aangemaakt`, '%b %Y') AS `label`,
            COUNT(*) AS `num`
        FROM `afwijkings_rapporten`
        WHERE `aangemaakt` >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()), 1) -- start of current year
          AND `aangemaakt` <  MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()) + 1, 1) -- start of next year
        GROUP BY `grp`, `label`
        ORDER BY `grp` ASC
        SQL;

// execute query
$result = $pdo->query($query);

//  you can just fetchAll as you are not manipulating the result set
$data = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// send header so jQuery knows what it's getting
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Then in your success handler you can assign the labels (months) and their values:

```js
let labels = [];
let values = [];

for(let row of data) {
    labels.push(row.label);
    values.push(row.num);
}
```